# What is the best way to reduce MXN table search in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables called tasks and users. All I want to do is I don't want to display the tasks that is already done by a user in his panel. Suppose the task table has about 1000 entries and there are about 50000 users. Also the users and the tasks keep increasing.

One solution I can think of, 1st is creating a separate table of task x user size.
For example:
user table

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| user_id | fname  | lname |
+---------+--------+-------+
|       1 |   John | Smith |
|       2 |  Steve | Mark  |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

task table

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| task_id |    task     | task_duration |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |   Do task 1 | 1 hour        |
|       2 |   Do task 2 | 1 hour        |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

Creating a separate table called display

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| display_id | task_id | user_id |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |       1 |       1 |
|          2 |       1 |       2 |
|          3 |       2 |       1 |
|          4 |       2 |       2 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

So only listed tasks will be shown to the particular user.

The problem is that This does not look like an efficient solution. How can I design table in this scenario in an efficient way. If not what are the other ways?

Comment: Looks efficient to me

Comment: - display_id seems redundant though